# Getting an approximate analytical form for eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a 20x20 matrix:

```
myMat = {{-(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) +    e, c, (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]),   (-I/4)*(I + Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, -(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), d, -c,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, 0,   (-I/4)*(I + Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, -(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) +    e, -c, (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8, 0, 0,   ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x])/4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, -(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8, d, c,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, 0, 0, 0,   ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x])/4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, -(c/Sqrt[6]) - d/Sqrt[2] + e, 0,   -(c/Sqrt[3]) - d, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Sin[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Cos[x])/2, 0, -(Sqrt[3]*c) + d, 0,   -(Sqrt[2/3]*c) + e, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Sin[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {(-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e,   (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) +    e, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8, -(c/Sqrt[6]) - d/Sqrt[2] + e, 0,   a/2, 0, 0, I*b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (-I/2)*b, b/2, 0},  {c, d, -c, d, 0, -(Sqrt[3]*c) + d, 0, a/2, (-I/2)*b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, (I/2)*b, 0, 0, -b/2}, {(2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, -c,   (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, c, -(c/Sqrt[3]) - d, 0, 0, (I/2)*b, a/2, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -b/2, 0, 0, (-I/2)*b},  {(c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) -    (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, 0, -(Sqrt[2/3]*c) + e,   (-I)*b, 0, 0, a/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b/2, (I/2)*b, 0},  {((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x])/4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) +    e, c, (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2])},  {0, ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x])/4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), d, -c,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e},  {0, 0, (-I/4)*(I + Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, -c,   (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8},  {0, 0, 0, (-I/4)*(I + Sqrt[3])*a*Sin[x], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, 0, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8, d, c,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e},  {0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Sin[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, -(c/Sqrt[6]) - d/Sqrt[2] + e, 0,   -(c/Sqrt[3]) - d, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(a*Sin[x])/2, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (a*Cos[x])/2, 0, -(Sqrt[3]*c) + d, 0,   -(Sqrt[2/3]*c) + e}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (-I/2)*b, -b/2, 0,   (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e,   (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), (-7*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - d/(4*Sqrt[2]) +    e, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8, -(c/Sqrt[6]) - d/Sqrt[2] + e, 0,   -a/2, 0, 0, (-I)*b}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I/2)*b, 0, 0, b/2, c, d,   -c, d, 0, -(Sqrt[3]*c) + d, 0, -a/2, (I/2)*b, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b/2, 0, 0, (-I/2)*b, (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, -c,   (2*c)/Sqrt[3] - d, c, -(c/Sqrt[3]) - d, 0, 0, (-I/2)*b, -a/2, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -b/2, (I/2)*b, 0,   (c - Sqrt[3]*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]), (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) -    (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, (-(Sqrt[2]*c) + Sqrt[6]*d)/8,   (-5*c)/(4*Sqrt[6]) - (3*d)/(4*Sqrt[2]) + e, 0, -(Sqrt[2/3]*c) + e,   I*b, 0, 0, -a/2}}
(*empty line*)
```

I know that in general it is impossible to get the analytic expressions for the eigenvalues of `myMat`. However, if Mathematica returns these `Root` objects, one can series expand them and obtains some nice approximate forms (after applying `ToRadicals`).

The Problem here is, Mathematica seems to take forever to compute the characteristic polynomial (I have been waiting for days now). Since the matrix contains more than 50% zeros I wonder if one can apply a different method than the default `Eigenvalues` to get results faster. I also noticed that `Eigenvalues` takes up quiet some memory. For a 14x14 matrix I noticed that the end result was huge even though Simplify easily reduced it by quiet a bit in size. Maybe, one could employ `Laplace's formula` due to the amount of zeros.

Comment: Since you will be getting approximate forms anyway, why not use `Eigenvalues[N[myMat]]`? For a 20x20 matrix it will be so fast that you can do it for many different values of your parameters...

Comment: Numerically I have already looked at this matrix. But now I would really like to verify that the eigenvalues have - in the approximate regime - the functional form that I suspect.

Comment: Is `myMat` supposed to be Hermitian? What about positive definite?

Comment: I would like to know the values of those constants so that I can examine it numerically too.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Hermitian, so all EVs are real, but not positive definite.

Comment: @bobbym they are not constants, that is the issue. They are all parameters. So analyzing the matrix numerically is annoying due to the large number of parameters.

Comment: If some of the parameters are assumed to be small, the usual approach is to apply [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#Time-independent_perturbation_theory).

Comment: @SimonRochester The small parameters here could be e.g. `c`,`d`,`x`. This, however, would lead to degeneracies in the unperturbed system, which in turn would force me to increase the parameters that I have to include in the initial diagonalization which leads me back to my problem.